# Why does Guy's dad hate SheZow so much?

Tags: shezow

Guy Hamdon (who is secretly SheZow) - has a father who's a police officer, who pretty obviously hates SheZow for most of the first season (he's shown to start to soften a bit after SheZow lets him handle certain cases).

[image: Officer Hamdon]

Do we know *why* he hates SheZow so much?